# Turborepo deploy with vercel fails for nextjs projects

Tags: deployment, vercel, next.js13, monorepo, turborepo

I tried to deploy a monorepo which was built using turborepo. Inside the app folder of the monorepo, there are two different nextjs apps:

1. my-next-app
2. on-test-i18n

I tried to keep the on-test-i18n as the base app.

Framework Preset:
Next.js
Build Command:
cd ../.. && npx turbo run build --scope=on-test-i18n
Root Directory:
apps/on-test-i18n

both my apps were built using nextjs app directory. Whenever I try to deploy, it shows up an error:
[image]

But it works perfectly and the routes-manifest.json file also generates successfully inside the .next directory when I build it locally.

I've tried changing the base app to my-next-app but it fails as well.